# Set values of all dropdowns while document.ready, all five dropdowns are cascading

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I have five cascading dropdowns (on selection of 1st 2nd Dropdown is filled using `Ajax` call, on change of 2nd 3rd is filled and so on).
when i left system last time i might have some values filled in all of them and are Saved in DB.
While logging in i want to set all values again but things will go in a flow.
for an eg.

> If Country was India then it will set the value as India and fire Country dropdown's OnChange event and state's dropdown is filled, but i am not able to set the selected value of state.

I am stuck at this point. 1st trigger change is working fine and ajax call resulting in filling 2nd Dropdown. but 2nd value is not setting. and thus further flow has stopped.

here's the code.

```
$(window).bind('load', function () {
    if ('@DealerSavedValue' != "") {            
        $('#ddldealer').val('@DealerSavedValue').trigger('change');
    }

    if ($('#ddldealer').val()!="" && '@CompanySavedValue' != "") {
            $('#ddlcompany').val('@CompanySavedValue').trigger('change');
    }
    if ($('#ddlcompany').val()!="" && '@ServerSavedValue' != "") {
                $('#ddlserver').val('@ServerSavedValue').trigger('change');
    }
    if ($('#ddlserver').val()!="" && '@ServiceSavedValue' != "") {
        $('#ddlservices option[value="@ServiceSavedValue"]').attr("selected", "true");
    }
})
```

**Notes:**

value with @ are values from database and are to be set as selected
once Dealer's value is set Selected, it will get Company names according to dealer, and then Company's value should be set selected. and this is not happening.

`Once All Dropdowns are bind and i fire same syntax for Trigger from console it is working.`

please help if anyone have solution.